# Compile Visual Studio projects without having Visual Studio installed?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, sdk, compilation

Is there a way to compile a Visual Studio 2012 project without having the VS installed? I need to compile C++ stuff for windows quite rarely and buying the product is not justified as there's no profit (community projects). In most of the cases the project and solution files will be available. If there's a way to compile the code with SDK, could you please share an example?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is likely going to be using [msbuild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wea2sca5%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) which will allow you to build a solution or project without having Visual Studio installed.

Comment: From the SDK page you link to, contradicting the claim that it includes compiler etc.: "The Windows SDK no longer ships with a complete command-line build environment. You must install a compiler and build environment separately. If you require a complete development environment that includes compilers and a build environment, you can download Visual Studio 2013, which includes the appropriate components of the Windows SDK."

Comment: msbuild.exe Project.sln /t:Rebuild /p:Configuration=Release

Answer (score 2):

You can download visual studio express for free.  Whenever you build a solution, the bin folder in your project folder will contain the compiled code.

http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs.aspx

EDITED: (per MS website)

Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows Desktop enables the creation of desktop apps in C#, Visual Basic, and C++, and supports Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF), Windows Forms, and Win32.
Sign in to Visual Studio within 30 days with your Microsoft account to synchronize your settings across multiple machines and register your product.

Comment: But the express has 90days evaluation period? Can I reinstall it every time with a new evaluation period? If that's the case, then it is more than ok for me!

Comment: Express should not have a 90 day evaluation period.  It may require you get a free license within 90 days using a free microsoft Live account

Comment: you just have to register to continue using the product. the days of including the c++ compiler with the SDK are, sadly, over. still, after installing e.g. visual studio express for desktop, you can use the compiler (and also the build system) from the command line.

Comment: Well, that's what I need to know.. what commands should I execute to compile and link?

Comment: http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9709949
Visual Studio Express 2010 does have a C++ version and is still downloadable.  Depends on what you are doing what option will work best.  If you're taking a basic programming class, I would consider using the bloodshed C++ link provided.

Comment: @vigour: the installation directory tree contains at least one `vsvars32.bat` file to set up paths etc. then, **CL** invokes the compiler, which by default also invokes the **LINK** linker. options for these tools can be placed in environment variables with the same names. not sure about options for **MSBUILD**.

Comment: @VoteCoffee - VS 2010 does not have the 64bit compiler :( and to make it run I need to install a whole bunch of other things, while VS2012 comes with built in 64bit compiler

Comment: @vigour: VS2013 includes a C++ compiler.  I updated my first comment with notes from the website.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the free version VC++ Express installed (and thus the compiler toolchain), you might find it more interesting to use Eclipse CDT as IDE on top. At least the newer versions (I think since Helios) support using the native MS toolchain. You can import from native 
VS projects also.

Eclipse is the more powerful IDE IMHO, and will additionally support other toolchains (either cross compiling, or Windows alternatives as MinGw GCC).